# How do I rename an item with add-ons?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

How do I change the in-game display name of a block or item with add-ons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rename items, in your resource pack, create a `texts` folder in the root directory. In `texts`, create a file that is the language code `.lang`. For example, United States would be `en_US.lang`, and the United Kingdom would be `en_GB.lang`. There is a different file for each language.
In each file, in the language it is in, to rename blocks, do this:

```
tile.block-id.name=Custom Name
```

And to rename items, do this:

```
item.item-id.name=Custom Name
```

If it is a custom item or block, use

```
tile.pack-name:blck-id=Custom Name
```

or

```
item.pack-name:block-id=Custom Name
```

Comment: Make sure to include the prefix for non-vanilla things